# Creating a symbolic link with Java

Tags: java, symlink

I'm having trouble creating a symbolic link to a directory in Java. I'm using the createSymbolicLink() method from the Files class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Absolute paths:

- Target: `/some/path/target`
- Link: `/some/path/xxx/linkname`

I would expect that a link in the directory `/some/path/xxx/` is created to the folder `/some/path/target`, but instead a link from `/some/path/xxx/linkname` to `/some/path/xxx/target` is created. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

When I create a link from `/some/path/linkname` to `/some/path/target`, everything works as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
Here's my code:

```
Path records = Paths.get(Properties.getProperty("records.path"));
Path recordsLink = Paths.get(Properties.getProperty("webserver.root") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + records.getFileName());
try {
    Files.createSymbolicLink(recordsLink, records);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The "records.path" and "webserver.root" are both relative paths.

**Actually I just found a solution to the problem**: It works if I do this:

```
records = records.toAbsolutePath();
```

I assumed the `createSymbolicLink()` will use absolute paths to create the links, which was wrong.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: I found a solution. See edited post.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to put answers there. Even if you found the answer to your question yourself do put it in a proper answer.

Comment: I would have, but with less than 10 reputation, I have to wait 10 hours before I can post an answer to my own question.

Comment: 10 hours have passed :)

Comment: I believe the root of this problem is the location of the `cwd` (current working directory)..  Which under java can sometimes be _anywhere_.  If one wanted to use a relative path; you need to `cd` to the folder where you want the link.  See: [Java Change File Working Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19009205/108350)

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution to the problem: It works if I do this:

```
records = records.toAbsolutePath();
```

I assumed `createSymbolicLink()` will use absolute paths to create the links, which was wrong.

Comment: Not sure why you're converting from path to string to path -- `records = records.toAbsolutePath()` is equivalent.