# Java Change File Working Directory

Tags: java, io

I'm writing some unit tests. I'm running the tests by invoking the classes directly (rather than invoking another program).  The problem is that some of these classes use data defined by relative paths, so they require that the program is started in a specific directory.  How can I change this in Java?

For instance, my unit test starts in `C:/unittest`, and the data I need is in `C:/OtherProject`.  I don't want to modify the code of the other project if possible, is there something like this in java:

```
File.setWorkingDir("C:/OtherProject");
```

That way when something like

```
File file = new File("data/data.csv");
```

Will read `C:/OtherProject/data/data.csv` instead of `C:/unittest/data/data.csv`.

Comment: How about getting a copy of the data for testing purposes in the testing-dir?

Comment: ASAIK, there is nothing like that available.

Comment: That's why people use database to share the same data, manage the same data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Updating my answer, since VolkerSeibt pointed out that it was incorrect. Good catch.

This is possible through `System.setProperty`. You can change the current working directory by changing the `"user.dir"` system property:

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", "/foo/bar");
```

See http://www.javacodex.com/Files/Set-The-Current-Working-Directory for further explanation.

Comment: I've done quite a lot of looking round, this does seem the case.  I've solved it by just having a static class 'FileUtil' that I store the working directory in (and have accessors), and then a function 'loadFile' which essentially just prepends the working directory to the passed file path.

Comment: Thats wrong. See http://www.javacodex.com/Files/Set-The-Current-Working-Directory . Works at least on windows and linux.

Comment: This is still incorrect. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202127